# Can I move the cloud of daggers around to different areas, or do I have to recast it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

We're playing 5e next week, and I just unlocked the Cloud of Daggers spell. I am wondering if this can be moved around the room. It doesn't say whether or not the Cloud of Daggers is a stationary spell or not.

I'm wondering if I can move it back and forth across a hallway to catch multiple monsters that are moving back and forth, or going around the room. Maybe use it to cut ropes on multiple areas holding up a door, destroy writing on a wall, and the like.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. One of the core tenets in 5e is that spells do only exactly what they say.

In this case, since the spell does not say you can move it, you cannot. If you cast it again, you may target a different location, however.