# Can you cast Hallow on yourself?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

I can't  find a definite answer  as this seems to be some gray area in the ruling. What would be cool is to spend 24 hours casting hallow on yourself, covering a 60 ft space with an affect, darkness for example. If you are a shadow monk, you could  teleport 60 ft in any direction as a bonus action. Potentially surprising a creature as one way to use this or grapple an enemy while you can fly, teleport 60ft up and release.

> **Hallow**
>
> **You touch a point** and infuse an area around it with holy (or unholy) power. The area can have a radius up to 60 feet, and the spell fails if the radius includes an area already under the Effect a hallow spell. The affected area is subject to the following Effects.

Most spells have ranges expressed in feet. Some spells can target only a creature (including you) **that you touch**. Other spells, such as the shield spell, affect only you. These spells have a range of self.

Spells that create cones or lines of effect that originate from you also have a range of self, indicating that the **origin point of the spell's effect must be you.**

Once a spell is cast, its effects aren't limited by its range, unless the spell's description says otherwise.

> A typical spell requires you to pick one or more targets to be affected by the spell's magic. A spell's description tells you whether the spell targets creatures, objects, or **a point of origin for an area of effect** (described below).
>
> **Sphere**
>
> You select a sphere's **point of origin**, and the sphere extends outward from that point. The sphere's size is expressed as a radius in feet that extends from the point.
>
> A sphere's point of origin is included in the sphere's area of effect.

I've seen several answers saying that the hallow spell cannot move, but how I see it RAW you can cast it on yourself.

Answer (score 14):

#### When spell areas can move, the spell description states this.

For example, the *[darkness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness)* spell:

> [...] If the point you choose is on an object you are holding or one that isn't being worn or carried, the darkness emanates from the object and moves with it. [...]

Because the *hallow* spell never mentions its area of effect moving with the target, it does not move.

Answer (score 7):

### It doesn't work this way

The PHB on p.201 says about targeting spells:

> Typically, a point of origin is a point in space, but some spells have an area whose origin is a creature or an object.

That means if you pick a "point in space" that happens to be on an creature, and then the creature moves, the point remains where it is. It does not move with the creature. For that to happen the origin of the spell would need to be the creature.

[Delayed Blast Fireball](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/delayed-blast-fireball) is special in that it allows you to create a pebble that can be thrown, and that then can explode into a fireball. Likewise, [Darkness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) explicitly states that you can pick a point on an object, and the darkness will move with it.

Spells only do [what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret).

See also this [question on catapult](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196064/can-you-catapult-another-spells-point) (which is asking the same for an object).